# Installation of Netkit-Ng on CentOS

Tags: centos

I want to install Netkit-ng on CentOS, I executed those commands :

```
tar -xjSf netkit-ng-core-32-3.0.4.tar.bz2
tar -xjSf netkit-ng-filesystem-i386-F7.0-0.1.3.tar.bz2
tar -xjSf netkit-ng-kernel-i386-K3.2-0.1.3.tar.bz2

export NETKIT_HOME=/home/admin/Desktop/netkit
export PATH=$PATH:$NETKIT_HOME/bin
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$NETKIT_HOME/man


./check_configuration.sh
```

This is what I get by running the last one :

```
[root@localhost netkit]# ./check_configuration.sh
>  Checking path correctness... passed.
>  Checking environment... passed.
>  Checking for availability of man pages... passed.
>  Checking for proper directories in the PATH... passed.
>  Checking for availability of auxiliary tools:
    awk          : ok
    basename     : ok
    date         : ok
    dirname      : ok
    find         : ok
    getopt       : ok
    grep         : ok
    head         : ok
    id           : ok
    kill         : ok
    ls           : ok
    lsof         : ok
    ps           : ok
    readlink     : ok
    wc           : ok
    port-helper  : ok
    tunctl       : ok
    uml_mconsole : ok
    uml_switch   : ok
passed.
>  Checking for availability of terminal emulator applications:
    xterm          : found
    konsole        : not found
    gnome-terminal : found
passed.
>  Checking filesystem type... passed.
>  Checking whether executables can run... failed!

*** Error: Your system appears not to be able to run the linux kernel.


[ ERROR ] Your system is not configured properly. Please correct the
          above errors before starting to use Netkit.
```

How can I fix that? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message comes from the file `netkit-ng/check_configuration.d/09-check_architecture.sh`, in which the following check is performed:

```
if ! $NETKIT_HOME/kernel/netkit-kernel --help >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "failed!"
   echo
   echo "*** Error: Your system appears not to be able to run the linux kernel."
   echo
   check_failure
fi
```

Judging from that, it's possible that the `$NETKIT_HOME` environment variable is not set, or the file `$NETKIT_HOME/kernel/netkit-kernel` is not execute (on my system it was).

Also note that Netkit-NG seems to be built for Debian, so it might be impossible or very difficult to run it on CentOS.

Comment: The environment variables are all set and I installed netkit before successfuly on CentOS in another machine without any problem.